# Sparql query: find objects with same property objects

Tags: rdf, sparql

Suppose we have a dataset that looks like this:

```
:person :wantsCD :cd1; :wantsCD :cd2 .
:storeA :sellsCD :cd1; sellsCD :cd2; sellsCD :cd3 .
:storeB :sellsCD :cd1; sellsCD :cd10; sellsCD :cd100 .
```

I'm interested in finding the stores that sell all the CD's `:person` wants, i.e. (`:storeA`). Is it possible to get this result with a SPARQL query? The query should also work when the number of CD's the `:person` wants is unknown at runtime.  I tried:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?store ?cd
WHERE { 
 :person :wantsCD ?cd.
 ?store :sellsCD ?cd.
}
```

but this returns both `:storeA` and `:storeB`, since `:storeB` also sells `:cd1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Solution

> I'm interested in finding the stores that sell all the CD's :person
>   wants, i.e. (:storeA). Is it possible to get this result with a SPARQL
>   query?

Yes, the trick is to do something that matches *all* the stores, and then filters out those for which there is a CD that the person wants that the store does not have:

```sql
select ?store where {
  #-- matches every store that sells any CD.
  ?store :sellsCD []

  #-- make sure there is no CD that the person wants
  #-- that the store does not sell.
  filter not exists { 
    :person :wantsCD ?cd    #-- There is no CD that :person wants
    filter not exists {
      ?store :sellsCD ?cd   #-- that ?store does not sell.
    }
  }
}
```

### Notes

Thank you very much for providing sample data to work with.  Just as a note that might make your life a bit easier, in addition to the `;` notation that you used in, e.g.:

```
:person :wantsCD :cd1; :wantsCD :cd2
```

there's also a `,` notation for multiple objects of the same property.  You can write that line as:

```
:person :wantsCD :cd1, :cd2
```